# copying file, file not disposed

Tags: c#, io

I have the following code for copying file:

```
var copedFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToFirebirdDB"] + ".001";

using (var inputFile = new FileStream( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToFirebirdDB"],
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var outputFile = new FileStream(copedFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        int bytes;

        while ((bytes = inputFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine only one time. The next time I get the folowing message:

```
 The process cannot access the file 'D:\Programs\IBExpert\db.fdb.001' because it is being used by another process. System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\Programs\IBExpert\db.fdb.001' because it is being used by another process.
```

Why? There are `using` block.

Comment: This file is opened and locked by Firebird... This is not your code which is faulting

Comment: Is anyone else accessing the output file (`copedFile`)? Assuming the file does not initially exist, the first time through it will be created, and the second time it will be overwritten. Perhaps someone else has opened the file and it can't be overwritten?  That someone else might be your code, or perhaps a virus scanner as pointed out in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to reopen the file just after closing it, there is a chance the file is still considered open by the system because it actually is.

A typical reason is that a virus scanner is keeping the file open to ensure it is not infected, this happens in the background and might continue running after you have closed the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are not closing the files.

BTW why don't you just use `File.Copy`?

Comment: because the source file is using another application. And `File.Copy` does not copy. This solution works.

Comment: Roy's question is pertinent. Why downvoting?

Comment: Could be because the answer is wrong I guess? `using (...)` when the objects are filestreams will in fact close the files when the code leaves the using-block.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this is wrong: "Probably because you are not closing the files." - the using statements are enough to close the files.

Comment: Regardless, it is silly to be writing functionality that is 100% present in the framework, debugged and all.

Comment: @RoyDictus, I don't believe `File.Copy` has an option to copy a file that is open for writing like in the OP's code (`FileShare.ReadWrite`).